# How to fire onload event for Image() on Android with Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to trigger function on "onload" event of Image() (HTMLImageElement) on Android with Ionic 3. It works with iOS but unfortunately doesn't work with Android.

How can I trigger **onload** function on Android? I do not use it with `<img>` or other tag, so I cannot fire it with `<img (load)="functionHere()">`.

(I have seen some of the other "onload" questions on Stack Overflow, this is about a specific situation with Android/Ionic 3).

Here is my example code:

```
this.backgroundImageSource = new Image();
this.backgroundImageSource.src = this.image;


this.backgroundImageSource.onload = function() {
    // THIS PART DOESNT FIRE ON ANDROID
    console.log("ONLOAD TRIGGERED");
}
```

Comment: I wonder why you would need to use an HTMLImageElement instead of <ion-img> or even <img> if you are building an Ionic app ?

Comment: @SebinBenjamin I use it for image manipulation with KonvaJs

Answer (score 0):

If the example code is used exactly as shown, then the issue could be with `onload` event handler being defined after the event could happen. You should define the event handler function before the event could occur.

So `onload` must be handled before `src` attribute is set. Although, I'm not sure if the JS engine fixes this in any of its optimization steps.

```
this.backgroundImageSource = new Image();

//This has to be done before setting src
this.backgroundImageSource.onload = function() {
    console.log("ONLOAD TRIGGERED");
}

this.backgroundImageSource.src = this.image;
```

Comment: in fact .onerror gets triggered and I realized Ionic cannot read file from Android emulator/device. Trying to find reason for that now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I discovered that the base64 did not include a header/descriptor and so for that reason it was not firing.

I fixed this by appending a header in cases where one did not exist:

```
if (!base64Data.includes(',')) {
  // Detect if base64 image is missing header/descriptor
  console.log("Prepending descriptor to Base64 image string")
  base64Data = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Data}`;
}
```

(The comma is used to separate the header from the body).